# Category pagination not working

Tags: categories, pagination

My category page navigation doesn't seem to be showing up at all, what am I missing in my coding?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="inner-page">
  <div class="page-spacer"></div>
  <!-- Content Start -->
  <div id="content-top"></div>
  <div id="category-content-wrapper">
    <div id="category-content" role="main">
      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
      <header class="page-header">
        <div class="page-title category-title">
          <h1>
            <?php
                        printf( __( '%s', 'rsi' ), '' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '' );
                    ?>
          </h1>
        </div>
        <?php
                        $category_description = category_description();
                        if ( ! empty( $category_description ) )
                            echo apply_filters( 'category_archive_meta', '<div class="category-archive-meta">' . $category_description . '</div>' );
                    ?>
      </header>
            <?php wp_pagenavi() ?>
      <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
      <?php
$args = array( 'category' => 5 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
      <div class="post-holder">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div id="custom-bg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"> </div>
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="blog-title">
          <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="blog-excerpt">
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
                <div class="blog-date"> Posted on:
          <?php the_date(); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php else : ?>
      <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
        <header class="entry-header">
          <h1 class="entry-title">
            <?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'rsi' ); ?>
          </h1>
        </header>
        <!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
          <p>
            <?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'rsi' ); ?>
          </p>
          <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>
        <!-- .entry-content --> 
      </article>
      <!-- #post-0 -->

      <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_pagenavi() ?>
    </div>
    <!-- #content -->
    <div id="sidebar">
      <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Right Sidebar')) : ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clear-block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear-block"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear-block"></div>
<div id="content-bottom"></div>
<!-- Content End -->
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a closer look at the [http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy Template Hierarchy]. From what I understood in your code is that you're trying to list posts in the category where ID = 5. You can easily map that to the `category-slug.php` or `category-id.php` template files, so you won't have to do any extra `get_posts`.

The problem with pagination is that `wp_pagenavi` is looking for your `$wp_query` global and doing pagination for the original query (which you don't filter.) Or maybe the only reason is that your WP-PageNavi plugin is not installed or disabled ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have enough posts in your category for it to display page navigation?

I have just tried your exact code on my dev site and it works fine. However I had to set this setting to see the navigation markup produced by the plugin as I didn't have tnough posts in any specific category to warrant pagination:

**Always Show Page Navigation**

You will find this setting just under "Page Navigation Options" about half way down the PageNavi admin page in the "Settings" area of the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but u can user `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>`  after the foreach.

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

May it work for you.